# Filter in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a loop in VBA that loops through about 3000+ records and hides the ones that don't fit the criteria.  It works just fine but it runs SUPER slow.  Is there a faster or more efficient way to filter based on the following criteria? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim i As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range, rng5 As Range, j As Long, sheetName As String, rng6 As Range, rng7 As Range, rng8 As Range, rng9 As Range

Set rng1 = FindHeader("Client Exclusion List", Sheet8.Name)
Set rng2 = FindHeader("CLIENT NAME", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng3 = FindHeader("MARKET SEGMENT", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng4 = FindHeader("ARCHIVED", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng5 = FindHeader("FORMULARY NAME", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng6 = FindHeader("WEBSITE", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng7 = FindHeader("PDF", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng8 = FindHeader("HPMS EXPORTED", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng9 = FindHeader("SERFF EXPORTED", Sheet5.Name)

For i = 1 To rng2.Rows.Count
'Checks to see if the Client Name is in the Excluded list
    For j = 1 To rng1.Rows.Count

        If rng2.Cells(i, 1).Value = rng1.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            rng2.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

    Next j

    'Checks For all CMS records and hides the ones that are not from current year

    If Left(rng3.Cells(i, 1).Value, 8) = "CMS Part" Then
        If rng3.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "CMS Part D (CY " & Year(Date) & ")" Then
            rng3.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
    'Checks if record is archived
    If rng4.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Yes" Then
        rng4.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
'Checks if record contains "Test" or "Demo" in the Name
    If InStr(1, CStr(rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value), "test") > 0 Or InStr(1, CStr(rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value), "Test") > 0 Or InStr(1, CStr(rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value), "demo") > 0 Or InStr(1, CStr(rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value), "Demo") > 0 Or InStr(1, CStr(rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value), "TEST") > 0 Or InStr(1, CStr(rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value), "DO NOT USE") > 0 Then
        rng5.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: It would almost certainly be faster to actually use the AutoFilter or Advanced Filter functionality than to loop. Your first loop looks especially time consuming as you are reading cell by cell, and reading the same cells over and over again. There should be an `exit for` inside your inner loop too, as there's no point checking the same row again after you've hidden it. Using arrays would also speed that up.

Comment: How would I convert the conditions to use with AutoFilter or Advanced Filter?

Answer (score 1):

One small change that should help is adding

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

at the beginning and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

at the end

The screen updating time can be much more substantial than the logic.

**Edit** as an alternative to the array loop.  Creates a dictionary filled with the excluded items as keys before the big loop.  A set would be better here since you have a useless item to go with each key but I don't think VBA has those.

Instead of the loop through the range or an array you just check for the existence of the key in the dictionary.

```
   'before loop
    Dim excludedList As Object
    Set excludedList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To rng1.Rows.Count
        excludedList.Add rng1.Cells(i, 1).value, 1
    Next i

    '****************************************
    'in loop
    If excludedList.exists(rng2.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        rng2.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you. That speeds it up a little but it still takes 7+ minutes to complete the whole Sub.  Would there be a faster way to do it?

Comment: Wow, that's a long time.  How big are i and j?  Maybe try timing certain sections and seeing where the bottle necks are?  Debug.print "line id" & now()

Comment: Yeah. I found out the time consuming part is my first loop because it runs EVERY time.  I'm thinking about using autofilter or advanced filter to do the filtering.  How would I convert the conditions to be used in one of those filters?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that should be faster. It uses array, autofilter and doesn't process all the other ranges for each row of `rng2`:

```
Dim rng1                  As Range
Dim rng2                  As Range
Dim rng3                  As Range
Dim rng4                  As Range
Dim rng5                  As Range
Dim rng6                  As Range
Dim rng7                  As Range
Dim rng8                  As Range
Dim rng9                  As Range
Dim i                     As Long
Dim j                     As Long
Dim sheetName             As String
Dim vData1

Set rng1 = FindHeader("Client Exclusion List", Sheet8.Name)
Set rng2 = FindHeader("CLIENT NAME", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng3 = FindHeader("MARKET SEGMENT", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng4 = FindHeader("ARCHIVED", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng5 = FindHeader("FORMULARY NAME", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng6 = FindHeader("WEBSITE", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng7 = FindHeader("PDF", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng8 = FindHeader("HPMS EXPORTED", Sheet5.Name)
Set rng9 = FindHeader("SERFF EXPORTED", Sheet5.Name)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

vData1 = rng1.Value

For i = 1 To rng2.Rows.Count
    'Checks to see if the Client Name is in the Excluded list
    For j = LBound(vdata1, 1) To UBound(vdata1, 1)

        If rng2.Cells(i, 1).Value = vdata1(j, 1) Then
            rng2.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Exit For
        End If

    Next j
Next i

'Checks For all CMS records and hides the ones that are not from current year

rng3.AutoFilter 1, "<>CMS Part*", xlOr, "CMS Part D (CY " & Year(Date) & ")"
'Checks if record is archived
rng4.AutoFilter 1, "<>Yes"
'Checks if record contains "Test" or "Demo" in the Name
rng5.AutoFilter 1, "<>*test*", xlAnd, "<>*demo*"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: It gave me a type mismatch on the first line of the second for loop. `For j = LBound(vdata, 1) To UBound(vdata, 1)`

Comment: And the filters do not filter anything.

Comment: I've just corrected a couple of typos - please test again.

Comment: That fixed that error. Now it gives me an object required error on: `If rng2.Cells(i, 1).Value = vData1(j, 1).Value Then`

Comment: Another typo - fixed now! (sorry)